# Extracting terraform resource changes with github-script@v5 action

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, github-actions

I have a github workflow where I want to filter the terraform destroy changes from the terraform plan file and post that as comment in the PR.

```
    - name: Terraform Plan
      id: plan_json
      run: |
        terraform plan -out planfile 2>error.log
        terraform show -json planfile > plan.json
      continue-on-error: true

    - uses: actions/github-script@v5
      id: message
      if: ${{ always() }}
      with:
        result-encoding: string
        script: |
          const fs = require('fs');
          const report = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./plan.json'));

          var message = '';
          for (const changes in report.resource_changes) {
            message += `${changes.change.actions[0]} ${changes.name} (${changes.type})\n`
          };

          console.log('Message: ', message);
          return message;
```

When I run the workflow it gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at callAsyncFunction (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:4942:56), <anonymous>:4:21)
    at callAsyncFunction (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:4943:12)
Error: Unhandled error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at main (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:4997:26)
    at Module.272 (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:4981:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:24:31)
    at startup (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:43:19)
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:49:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v5/dist/index.js:52:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
```

I don't have any nodejs/javascript experience so I have no clue what I am doing wrong here.

The actual plan file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/dGmZpdkx).

When I run the nodejs [script](https://pastebin.com/84XmxBC6) locally it works.

```
❯ node tfplan.js
Message:  create, rg (azurerm_resource_group)
create, rg-name (random_pet)
```

Comment: The error reads like `fs.readFileSync('./plan.json')` is nto returning JSON. Try capturing the result of fs.readFileSync in to a variable and then pass this variable to JSON.parse. You should be able to debug this to check that the result of the file read is actually valid JSON.

Comment: Hi @phuzi thanks for your reply! here (https://pastebin.com/d27xH19p) you can see the exact output of plan.json and when I query it with jq it works fine.

Comment: I still recommend splitting `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./plan.json'))` and console logging the result of `fs.readFileSync('./plan.json')` to confirm that the content is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
      with:
        terraform_wrapper: false
```

terraform_wrapper: false had to be added to the terraform setup task.
For more info check [this](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/08/25/how-to-use-terraform-output-in-a-github-action/).